# inverse percent (% ^ -1) units symbol

Tags: notation, percentages

I have a graph showing bias and sensitivity of a psychometric curve (specifically, as logistic function of the form 
$\frac{1}{1+\exp(k(x-x_0))}$
, with $k$ = sensitivity and $x_0$ = bias). I am expressing my $x$ as a percentage of a reference stimulus, and therefore my normalized bias ($norm. bias = \frac{bias}{reference} *100$
) has units of percentage ([%]). What units does my normalized sensitivity have? ($norm. sensitivity = \frac{sensitivity * reference}{100}$). I know they are techinically both unitless, but I am unsure whether in a scientific graph I should specify that the sensitivity value was multiplied by $100$ - something like 
$\frac{1}{\%} $ or $\%^{-1}$ .

Thanks!

Comment: Neither the percent, nor $\%^{-1}$ are actual units, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: You do not exponentiate anything other than unitless numbers. Exponentiation does not intermix with units at all. therefore $k$ must have the inverse units of $x$ and $x_0$. Since $\%$ scales the value, it does count as a unit, but it remains an unnecessary one. Instead I would consider $x$ as a ratio out of $1$, and merely use $\%$ when giving values without bothering to explain, because after all, no explanation is necessary. Everybody knows what it means.

Answer (score 1):

The direct inverse of hundredths (percent when multiplied by a quantity) is hundreds. But I would probably care more, about using `\cdot` for multiplication, and labelling with function names, or formulae instead. That way, people can read it regardless of units. Also, using delimiters to properly show math, might be good. But percentages are relative. Markup percentages, are not the same as margin percentages. At least not when inverting things. Anyways have fun.[How to get an accurate result in the following problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210126/how-to-get-an-accurate-result-in-the-following-problem/3211706#3211706)