# For given $ab\leq n$, do there exist $a'\geq a$ and $b'\geq b$ such that $a'b'=n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For example, given $a=3$, $b=3$, and $n=14$, no such $a',b'$ exists. On the other hand, for $a=3$, $b=3$, and $n=12$, we can use $a'=3$ and $b'=4$.

Is there a simple formula that can help determine the answer to this question, rather than simply searching through possible combinations of $a'$ and $b'$?

Comment: It would boil down to factorizing the number you have. However, if the square root of the number is lesser than both a and b, then there does not exist any such pair.

Comment: It's clear that if $n$ is prime, then $a',b'$ will only exist if either $a=1$ or $b=1$.

Comment: Did you encounter this question somewhere, or is this a question that you've come up with yourself?

Comment: If you had such a method/formula, you could apply it to factor $n$ (assuming the method tells you what $a', b'$ are, you can just repeatedly set $a=2, b=2$ until you're left with primes). For large $n$, computationally, there is currently no particularly efficient method for integer factorization. If you do have the factorization, I don't know what to do in the general case beyond just listing the factors

Comment: Good point @xmq. I think that puts the nail in the coffin. On the other hand, if anyone else has more necessary OR sufficient conditions to share, I'd be glad to hear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no set formula to achieve this, AFAIK. What you can do is focusing on one variable, like $a'$, and finding the higest possible value such that the other variable is still in the allowed range:

$$a \le a' \le \left\lfloor\frac{n}b\right\rfloor \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

and then try every $a'$ in that range if it divides $n$.

One optimization method would be to test $n$ for 'large' prime factors $p$, but in our case 'large' already starts at $p=5$. Because if $n$ is divisible by some prime $p$, at least one of $a'$ and $b'$ need to be divisible by $p$.

So instead of testing all $a'$ that satisfy $\eqref{eq1}$, you test all $a'$ that satisfy $\eqref{eq1}$ and the additional condition that $p|a'$. But since you don't know if $a'$ or $b'$ will be divisble by $p$, you have to test all $b'$ with $p|b'$ and

$$b \le b' \le \left\lfloor\frac{n}a\right\rfloor \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

as well. But since you need to test only every $p$-th number, that should normally still be an advantage over the method without considering $p$.

Answer (score 0):

In reverse, it's related to the formula for [markup and margin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210126/how-to-get-an-accurate-result-in-the-following-problem/3211706#3211706). No possibility of such a factorization exists, with $ab=n$.  In fact: $$\sqrt{n}<a\land \sqrt{n}<b \implies n<ab<a'b'$$
Which is then a contradiction. One way would be:$${n\over ab}=(1+b_\text{markup})(1+a_\text{markup})$$ where you use percentage markup that can be integers when multiplied by b and a, respectively. But that's still more of a brute force approach.